# Uses for the Location vector of the Particle Info node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, particles

What can the Location values of the Particle Info node be used for? It seems to provide control of something like color or texture of particle instances, but I can't seem to implement that idea.

Can it be used in conjunction with the Point Density texture node?

Comment: Please show an example of your work to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Particle Distance to Some Particular Point**

[image]

The particles are colored differently within a certain distance to a given point P0.  Emission Shader. In the user ortho view is the cylinder with a particle system. The white torus has that same point P0 as center.  Image above.

[image]

Cycles Material Nodes calculating distance and employing color ramp.  Image above.

Click image above to see larger image.

The OP has asked about Textures Controlling Particles Systems.

This is a quick piece of information for further research.  The two columns are of the Particle Texture Settings which are visible only in Blender Internal Render Mode. Cycles will [not] show the same info, yet will be influenced by the textures as well. You can switch back and forth as [interesting] as this might seem.  The three yellow arrows emphasize Texture Panel Purpose, Mapping, and Influence areas.  This is not a tutorial on the topic.  I use two columns for the same settings out of edit convenience and readability convenience.

[image]

With a more complicated frame change handler and Python anything is possible. Same comment for BAN - Blender Animation Nodes.

Comment: wow!  your using my favorite font!

Comment: @X-27 How can you be sure?

Comment: Eurostile LT ExtendedTwo is an unmistakably awesome font - it can't possibly be mistaken for anything less awesome.

Comment: Nice example, atomicbezierslinger. Material color based on distance is something I had in mind. I undertstand the geometry of the emitter and the use of P0.

What I don't understand is relationship between the objects in the scene and the Material NodeTree you illustrated. Which object holds Material.023? Is it the torus duplicated with the cylinder's particle system? Is it the cylinder itself?

Comment: I tried both cases and discovered that the duplicated object should hold the Particle Info node. That kind of blows my mind since the duplicated object does not have a Particle System.

Is there a way to connect the Particle Info to a Point Density texture?

Comment: All objects have a particle info attached to them. If they are not part of a particle system then they might have particle index 0. Thus particle info is a convenience for objects without a particle system for uniformity of software. This happens often in software, uniformity with default values. Yes textures can control the density and placement and color et cetera of particles. Try searching and see what you find here at BSE. If you find nothing within 48 hours then please send a message..... See above edit.

Comment: Thank you again, atomicbezierslinger. Your explanation makes a lot of sense from a software perspective. I will continue to investigate!